# Adding HTML children and parent tabs to active class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I have this fly-out mene. This is the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="tab"><a class="active" href='#sw_operations'>Software Operations</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href='#software'>Software</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href='#fac_staff'>Fac/Staff Members</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href='#vendor'>Vendors</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href='#admin'>Admin</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#users'><span>Users</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='#variables'><span>Variables</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='#Reports'><span>Reports</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the JS:

```
$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".tab a").removeClass('active');
    $(".tab a").parent().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
    $(target).fadeIn(600);
});
```

What I am struggling with is, when the user hits one of the 3 children tabs, I want it to add that specific child tab to active class as well as it's parent. I have a CSS part for the tab being active.

How do I add the parent tab in addition to the child tab to active class in JS?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that :

```
<li class="tab"><a id='admin' href='#admin'>Admin</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href='#users' data-parent-id='admin'><span>Users</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#variables' data-parent-id='admin'><span>Variables</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#Reports' data-parent-id='admin'><span>Reports</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

```
$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(enter code here);
    $(".tab a").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(".tab #"+$(this).attr('data-parent-id')).addClass('active');
    target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();
    $(target).fadeIn(600);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this but there are several ways how to do this...
Firstly you add a child class to all of your `<li>` elements. Then you add an id of 'Admin' for example to your admin `<li>`.
Now in jQuery you can check if the element on which you pressed is of class child or not. If it is true then you can add the class of active to your Admin `<li>`.

Code:

```
<li class="tab" id="Admin"><a href='#admin'>Admin</a>
    <ul id="Children">
        <li><a class="child" href='#users'><span>Users</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="child" href='#variables'><span>Variables</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="child" href='#Reports'><span>Reports</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {
        if($(this).hasClass("child") == true) {
            $("#Admin").addClass('active');
        }
});
```

You just have to append the if statement to your code, I didn't include your code.